# Efficiency of the "parentNode" property of the DOM API?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I am about to write a piece of code that relies on `parentNode` to find an attribute from the DOM tree the current node is in.

For example:

```
<div data-url="https://www.google.com">
  <span>
    <a href='#' id='link'>Click me to get the url</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

From this markup I want to be able to click the `<a>` and get the `data-url` attribute of the closest ancestor element that contains `data-url`.

```
var getEnclosingUrl = function(){
  var link = document.getElementById('link');
  var parent = link;
  while(parent = parent.parentNode){
    if(parent.hasAttribute("data-url")){
      return parent.getAttribute("data-url");
    }
  }
  return "No url!";
}
```

The thing is I'm not sure how efficient this `parentNode` API is. Is it fast enough that I can just treat them like a regular javascript object (with an API)? or does it actually mess with reflows or have anything to do with actual rendered elements on screen?

Would appreciate any insights!

[EDIT] If accessing the DOM tree directly is not the best option, can anyone suggest a better alternative? By the way I am not concerned about the time it takes to preprocess stuff so if the solution involves preprocessing of some sorts that's also great.

[EDIT2] Updated to use "parentNode property" instead of "parentNode function"

[EDIT3] I think me giving this specific example may be a bit misleading because it's just one example. The bottom line is I already have a reference to a node (in this case `<a>`) and start from there, to get a specific attribute of the closest ancestor that contains the attribute.

Basically I'm looking for the most performant way to achieve this specific goal, and wasn't sure if using `parentNode` to traverse the DOM tree was good enough.

[EDIT 4] Let me clarify this even further. I want to be able to take ANY element in a DOM tree, like this:

```
var a = document.getElementById("test");
```

and access its attribute:

```
console.log(a.magicGetAttribute("data-url"))
```

And somehow automagically it will find the closest ancestor that has that attribute (if the current one doesn't), and return that value, like how JS prototype works.

Comment: as its a property it should be really fast to be accessed. At least faster then any Jquery etc. thing

Comment: @Xufox yes but i am guessing the polyfill internally uses parentNode anyway. Anyway my main concern is the performance issue, so if you have any insights on this department I would appreciate that as well!

Comment: I don't see where you got that "*accessing the DOM tree directly is not the best option*". Accessing the DOM is the *only* option when you want to find a node in the DOM tree.

Comment: You can also try `link.closest("[data-url]")`, although [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) isn’t supported by many browsers, but you may find a polyfill. What I said earlier about `parentNode` being just a property isn’t exactly true, because I forgot that it was actually a getter which has roughly the same overhead as a function.

Comment: @Bergi what I meant was it may be possible to use a different approach, where instead of traversing the DOM tree in realtime to get the attribute it may be possible to do a "preprocess" and generate some sort of a data structure which we can refer to. I was thinking something along the lines of how JS prototypes / Event bubbling / CSS property inheritance works. BTW NOT looking for "virtual DOM" as a solution as it's too heavy for my purpose. I only literally need to achieve what I described here.

Comment: See my updated answer for a much simpler solution.

Comment: @Vlad traversing the DOM is fast enough usually. Not sure what your "real time" requirements are. Please be more specific, or YAGNI. Of course you can always wrap your own (possibly precalculated) lookup data structure on top of it (especially when the tree doesn't change), but that's hardly worth the effort.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, I am basically trying to come up with a way to take any element from a DOM tree, and try to get its attribute. If it doesn't exist immediately on itself, it will somehow find the closest ancestor that contains that attribute and returns it.

Comment: @Vlad Yes, that's what your `getEnclosingUrl` function does. There really isn't any different algorithm. Do you have any real problem with the current code?

Comment: @Bergi The algorithm itself works fine, but I am not sure if this is something that I should use for production performance wise. I guess another way of asking this is, would this be almost as fast as creating a separate object tree just for this purpose (like the other alternative i mentioned)? I'm not looking for the most perfect solution, but I would be satisfied to learn that this is actually good enough.

Comment: @Vlad I suspect it's actually far faster than manually creating a separate tree structure. But to find out, you need to benchmark the two solutions on real world data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for the most performant way to achieve this specific goal, and *wasn't sure if* using `parentNode` to traverse the DOM tree *was good enough*.

Until you **know** from measurements that using `parentNode` **is not good enough**, don't try to perform any [premature optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation). Using the `parentNode` property is a fine way to traverse a DOM tree, it's not known for its inefficiency or something.

---

If there really is a problem, I'd rewrite `getEnclosingUrl` to a recursive approach and [memoise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) it using a `WeakMap`.

Comment: Thanks for the memoising tip. I think my concern comes from the fact that I don't know how it's internally implemented. Basically I am satisfied if all `parentNode` does is traverse an internal data structure without touching anything on the screen, which would mean it's not so different from creating any other separate data structure just for this type of traversal, because my only option would be to do exactly that--create a virtual dom tree just for this. would appreciate it if you could touch on this part.

Comment: Yes, getting `.parentNode` is `O(1)` and does not touch anything on the screen. Why would it?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

First, a couple of things to know about working with the DOM.

1. It is probably the slowest API to use.
2. Having said that, modern user agents have optimized the API pretty well, such that it's not the albatross it used to be and is pretty fast for most use cases as long as you don't abuse it by writing wasteful code (see below).

Searching the DOM, regardless of which method you use, does have overhead, but the search alone will not cause repaints or reflows.

Accessing property values (even read operations) adds additional overhead as well (so try to minimize DOM operations in loops). Generally, it's best to group multiple read operations into successive statements to optimize the operations.

Repaints and reflows only occur when you modify the content or style of elements. In those situations, there are steps you can take to minimize the re-rendering, such as working with elements that are in their own layer (minimizes reflows) and working with `opacity` when possible.

For your situation, it may be best to reverse the thinking. Instead of receiving the click event at the child and then searching for the parent, you can receive the event (through bubbling) at the parent because it was triggered by a child. Using **[`event.currentTaget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)** is helpful here and would eliminate the ancestor search loop entirely:

```js
// Get a list of all the "parent" elements
var dataURLs = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");

// Assign event handlers to all the parent elements
for(var i = 0; i < dataURLs.length; i++){
  dataURLs[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    // Get the value of the attribute ensuring to access
    // the object that the event was attached to, not the
    // object that initiated the event.
    console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.url || "No data-url!");  
  });
}
```

```html
<div data-url="https://www.google.com" class="parent">
  <span>
    <a href='#' id='link'>Click me to get the url</a>
  </span>
  <div>
    <!-- Even elements nested deeper within the parent will stil work -->
    <span>
      <a href='#' id='link'>Click me to get the url</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span>
    <a href='#' id='link'>Click me to get the url</a>
  </span>
</div>
<div data-url="https://www.microsoft.com" class="parent">
  <span>
    <a href='#' id='link'>Click me to get the url</a>
  </span>
</div>
<div data-url="https://www.apple.com" class="parent">
  <span>
    <a href='#' id='link'>Click me to get the url</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I was misleading with the example. Basically I have a very specific goal I want to achieve: I have a reference to a node, and from there I would like to get a specific attribute from the closest ancestor that has that attribute. Basically the first condition is that I start from the reference to the original node. So this solution while is really nice for the specific example I provided, cant' fundamentally solve my problem. Let me update the question to clarify!